# OSX Yosemite - JavaScript for Automation Accessing Enums

Tags: javascript, macos, applescript, osx-yosemite-beta, javascript-automation

I'm starting to try converting some of my AppleScripts into JavaScript in OS X Yosemite, but I don't understand how I'm supposed to access enums from applications.  For example - the status of Adium.

In AppleScript:

```
tell application "Adium"
    if status type of global status is offline then
        log "offline"
    end if
end tell
```

In JavaScript I do not know how to access the "offline" enum:

```
if(Application('Adium').globalStatus.statusType == ?????) {
    console.log("offline");
}
```

I've tried simple things like "offline" without success.
All these are errors:

```
Application('Adium').StatusType("offline"); // error
Application('Adium').StatusType.offline;     // undefined
Application('Adium').StatusType.make({name:"offline"}); // error
```

Anyone gotten something like this working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I have been unable to do the enum comparison, I have been able to make this work.  In JavaScript for automation, calling just the property returns the ObjectSpecifier for the Apple object.  In this case the statusType is a class of "AdiumRichText".

If you put () after the property it calls the getter method which returns a NSString (String) that works fine.  So here is the code:

```
if(Application('Adium').globalStatus().statusType() == "offline") {
    console.log("offline");
}
```

Comment: But still cannot get a value when enumeration value is required. I met the problem when use `createRecordWith` in DEVONthink, where argument `type` should be an enum value.